# Script fails to access the content in inside tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse a large xml file.

It has following structure.

```
    < merchandiser >
    <header></header>
    <product>
    <name></name>
    <URL>
        <info>
        </info>
        <product>
       </product>
    </URL>
    </product>

    ............

    <product>
    <name></name>
    <URL>
        <info>
        </info>
        <product>
       </product>

    </URL>
    </product>
    </merchandiser>
```

I am using iter.parse() from python-lxml library.

```
    for event , element in etree.iterparse(xmlfile,tag='product'):

        if element.tag=="product" and event == "end":
            if element.findall("..")[0].tag=='merchandiser':
                        print element.xpath('./URL/product/text()')
                        print element.xpath('./URL/info/text()')
        element.clear()
```

The script prints the text inside  tag but it fails to print the text inside  tag.

I think its because of  same tag names.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "The script prints the text inside tag but it fails to print the text inside tag."? Could you edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is iterating over all `product` elements and calling `clear()` on them, which removes all text and subelements. Since you're printing on the `end` event of the outer `product` elements, you are removing the text for the inner `product` elements before you print.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression: `./URL/product/text()` will find the text inside a `product` tag which is inside a `URL` tag, but not a `product` tag which is inside a `product` tag which is inside a `URL` tag.

Consider also using `./URL/product/product/text()` or `//product/text()` instead.